# "По несколько раз" или "по нескольку"?

Tags: склонение

Чаще говорят "по нескольку" и в текстах я такое встречала. Но, мне кажется, что это неграмотно — ведь наречия не склоняются. Я права?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Несколько" - это редкий случай, когда наречие склоняется, как прилагательное или числительное, если оно связано с зависимым словом (несколько раз, несколько человек и т.д.).
Несколько - им. пад.
нескольких - род. пад.
нескольким - дат. пад. и так далее.
Поэтому правильный вариант : "по несколькУ раз", так же, как и "по многУ раз". Но в современном русском языке, особенно в разговорном, допускается и форма "по несколькО раз". Так что, и тот, и другой вариант - правильный в принципе

Comment: По нескольку раз - по пять раз.  Несколько - неопределенное местоимение. Впервые слышу о склоняемых наречиях. Поделитесь ссылкой на источник, пожалуйста.

Comment: There are more things in heaven and earth, Horatio,   
Than are dreamt of in your philosophy.

Переводы - на выбор.
тут
http://www.lib.ru/SHAKESPEARE/hamlet_goracio.txt

Comment: Мне интересен лингвистический источник подобного утверждения. Цитата из Шекспира вряд ли подойдет.

Answer (score 7):

В таком сочетании это не наречие, местоименное числительное, оно может склоняться.
Во всяком случае так трактует Кузнецов.

А Лопатин дает варианты как равноправные. [Проверка слова: несколько](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%ED%E5%F1%EA%EE%EB%FC%EA%EE&all=x)

Answer (score 1):

местоимения сколько и несколько после предлога ПО употребляются в дательном падеже.

Именно формы по многу раз, по нескольку раз являются литературными, а по много раз, по несколько раз - разговорными (см. "Русский семантический словарь", т. 1, М., 1998).