# Окончание числительного "несколько" в дательном падеже

Tags: падежи

По нескольку раз.

Почему неопределенно-количественное числительное ***несколько*** имеет в дательном падеже окончание существительного  "у"? Ведь в остальных косвенных падежах оно совпадает с окончаниями прилагательных.

Comment: Разве это предложный падеж?

Comment: @Владимир Это не местоимение, а числительное (местоименное). http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE Это не предложный, а дательный падеж. На этом сайте уже есть такой вопрос (с решением). https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/24492/%d0%9f%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d1%83 (“По несколько раз” или “по нескольку”?)

Comment: Это слово склоняется и по образцу ед. числа прилагательного, и по образцу множ.? Могли бы вы употребить его в ед. ч. в родительном и предложном падежах?

Comment: Решение по ссылке я бы не назвала решением, так как мнения у отвечающих были разные. В действительности эта задачка потруднее,  чем о ней там говорили. Можно, конечно,  назвать правильную и разговорную форму - это нетрудно, сложнее объяснить, что это за формы. Да и дательный падеж - это скорее форма дательного падежа, а не сам падеж (устаревшая форма Д.п., как говорится в Грамматике-80). Здесь Владимир как раз прав, что сомневается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рассмотрим, как  склоняются неопределенно-количественные числительные и какой падеж обозначает окончание У с предлогом ПО.

**1. Склонение неопределенно-количественные числительных**

И.п. много, несколько/ многие

Р.п.  многих , нескольких

Д.п. многим, нескольким   (также по многу, по нескольку)

В.п. много, несколько/многие

Т.п.  многими, несколькими

Р.п.  о многих, о нескольких

Как можно видеть, **парадигма включает:**

1)  окончания существительных (вернее, кратких прилагательных, окончания которых совпадают с окончаниями существительных среднего рода); 2) окончания полных прилагательных.

Две формы числительного ***много*** и ***многие*** имеют разные оттенки значений.

**МНОГО,**  неопределенно-количественное числительное,  обозначает значительное количество предметов в однородном ряду.

**МНОГИЕ.**  Местоименное  прилагательное,  обозначает признак предметов, составляющих значительный по количеству однородный ряд.

Числительные  ***много*** и ***многие***  различаются в И.п. и В.п. *Собралось много народу. Я купил  много книг. Многие растения цветут летом. Ему вверили многие люди. В большевистской верхушке я знал многих людей. Жил я в чудную эпоху, знал много людей необыкновенных.*

В остальных падежах количественное и местоименно-определительное значения для ***много*** и ***многие*** имеют **одинаковые формы.**

У числительного ***несколько*** две формы значений также прослеживаются, но они не проявлены в падежных формах, хотя в некоторых случаях их надо различать.

Например, **в форме В.п.** возможны два варианта: *Я пригасил несколько друзей* (указано количество), *из своей  группы я пригласил только нескольких друзей*  (не всех, а выборочно, определительное значение).

Следует обратить внимание **на Р.п.,** в котором для выражения количественного значения могут использоваться формы И.п. и В.п. (так как эти падежи часто заменяют друг друга), например: *не хватает несколько книг* (количественная суммарная  оценка), сравнить: *не хватает нескольких книг, а именно* (определительное значение, не хватает конкретных книг).

**2. Распределительный (дистрибутивный) падеж числительных с предлогом ПО.**

Э**то особый падеж**, так как числительное в этом случае  управляет существительным, задавая ему Р.п. (отсутствует согласование, характерное для  **косвенных** падежей).

А вот сами числительные используются **в форме В.п. или Д.п.**,  причем  *два, три, четыре, сто, двести, триста, четыреста, двое, трое, четверо* – только В.п., а для остальных числительных Д.п. является **устаревающим**: *по тридцати рублей – по тридцать рублей*.

Но вот неопределенно-количественные числительные имеют  в этом падеже окончание Д.п. У (***по многу, по нескольку***), окончание О ненормативно.

**Но почему же не В.п., который практически используется для  всех  остальных числительных?**

Дело в том, что в Д.п. у этих числительных используются **две формы.**

***По многу лет, по нескольку месяцев***  – это окончание краткого прилагательного У в Д.п., выражающее **количественно-распределительное  значение числительного.**

Но эту форму **нужно отличать от обычной формы числительных в Д.п.**,  например:  *готовиться к экзаменам по нескольким книгам, это было ясно по многим признакам* (окончание прилагательного, согласование в падеже, нет управления).

Answer (score 3):

Несколько — это неопределенное местоименное числительное.

И. п. — несколько друзей; несколько дней
Р. п. — нескольких друзей; нескольких дней
Д. п. — нескольким друзьям; нескольким дням (по нескольку дней)
В. п. (одуш.) — несколько друзей (нескольких друзей)
В. п. (неодуш.) — несколько дней
Т. п. — несколькими друзьями; несколькими днями
П. п. — нескольких друзьях; нескольких днях

Д. Э. Розенталь ([§ 151. Формы винительного падежа одушевленных и неодушевленных существительных](https://info.wikireading.ru/69411)):
5. Из двух вариантов: встретить нескольких товарищей и **встретить несколько товарищей** — в настоящее время более употребителен второй (то же при словах сколько, столько)

К особенностям склонения этого числительного относится то, что в именительном и винительном падежах оно, подобно именам числительным, управляет падежом, то есть требует после себя определенного падежа существительного (а именно родительного множественного числа).
В остальных падежах это числительное склоняется как прилагательное, то есть согласуется с существительным.
Особая форма с "по", предлогом дательного падежа — по нескольку дней, по нескольку раз, по нескольку часов (Р. п. сохраняется; "по нескольку" — предпочтительнее).

В орфографическом словаре: несколько, нескольких; **по нескольку** и по несколько.

В толковом словаре:
1. НЕСКОЛЬКО, нескольких, по нескольку; ***местоим. числ.*** Некоторое, неопределённое (обычно небольшое) количество.

В словаре управления:
[несколько](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE) — 1. **по нескольку**, (разг.) **по несколько**. *Ещё раз запрещаю вам находиться в цехе неотлучно по нескольку дней (Аж.); Разместить по несколько человек в палатках.*

Comment: Я как раз вносила дополнения.

Comment: Не совсем понятно про управление падежом. Это означает, что числительное обуславливает форму существительного или формально сходится с ней?